# $M_2$ Function in MIRT R Package

Tags: item-response-theory, mirt

I am facing an error. The $M_2$ function is throwing an error when I have three items in a test. How can I resolve this?
[image: Error]

Comment: It looks like you have three items? I think that's not enough to estimate this.

Comment: With 3 items in the test you wouldn't really need the M2 family of statistics as the GOF information from the output above is likely saturated enough to indicate lack of fit. The M2 family is only necessary when the complete table of counts is too sparse to be reliable, so collapsing to first and second (or higher) moments corrects the sparseness.

Comment: It worked when I changed itemtype="graded" to "grsm".  As I have unidimensional and same type of categories in three items, I should be fine on this. Any thought about this this change?

Comment: Fewer model df will allow for this, though I still believe it is unnecessary given the response pattern expected values and counts. Use `residuals(mirt_asti, type='exp')` to see the table of counts per response pattern, and if the expected values are high (e.g., > 2) then the `G2` statistic reported above is likely close to optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to calculate the $M_2$ statistic (Maydeu-Olivares & Joe, 2006) or the $C_2$ statistic (Cai & Monroe, 2014)?  I ask because it is possible to calculate the $M_2$ with your model and data, though not the $C_2$. The reason for this is you lack degrees of freedom ($df$) to calculate the $C_2$, though you have plenty to calculate the $M_2$. With the $M_2$ you would have more than 0 $df$, so you would be fine.

You seem to have $m$ = 3 items, each with $K$ = 4 categories, resulting in $q$ = 12 estimated parameters. For the $C_2$ statistic this results in $m(K-1)+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}-q$ = $3(4-1)+\frac{3(3-1)}{2}-12$ = 0 degrees of freedom. Though with the $M_2$ You would have $m(K-1)+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}(K-1)^2-q$ = $3(4-1)+\frac{3(3-1)}{2}(4-1)^2-12$ = 24 degrees of freedom.

For more information on IRT model fit, I suggest you look at Maydeu-Olivares (2013, 2014).

Also, as an aside, I see you are using the Metropolis-Hastings Robbins-Monro (MHRM) algorithm (Cai, 2010) to fit your model. While the method is certainly state-of-the-art, it is typically applied in scenarios where you have more than one latent variable (e.g., I typically use it only when there are 4 or more correlated latent variables). Typically, when one fits a unidimensional IRT model, the Bock-Aitkin EM (BAEM) algorithm (Bock & Aitkin, 1981) is used, which I believe is the `mirt` default.

Finally, @philchalmers makes a good point in the comments when he suggests you use the $G^2$ statistic$^1$ instead of the $M_2$. The reason why limited information statistics such as the $M_2$ and $C_2$ are commonly used instead of full information statistics such as the $G^2$ and Pearson's $\chi^2$ is because the latter two involve the use of information from all $C = K^m$ possible response patterns. Without going into too much detail$^2$, this is an issue because both the $G^2$ and $\chi^2$ don't work well when the cells of the multinomial contingency table are sparsely populated. However, this should not be a problem for you as there are only $3^4 = 81$ possible response patterns.

$^1$ Often referred to as the likelihood ratio test statistic.

$^2$ See Cai et al. (2006) for more information.

**References**

Bock, R. D., & Aitkin, M. (1981). Marginal maximum likelihood estimation of item parameters: Application of an EM algorithm. Psychometrika, 46(4), 443-459.

Cai, L. (2010). Metropolis-Hastings Robbins-Monro algorithm for confirmatory item factor analysis. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 35(3), 307-335.

Cai, L., Maydeu‐Olivares, A., Coffman, D. L., & Thissen, D. (2006). Limited‐information goodness‐of‐fit testing of item response theory models for sparse 2P tables. British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 59(1), 173-194.

Cai, L., & Monroe, S. (2014). A New Statistic for Evaluating Item Response Theory Models for Ordinal Data. CRESST Report 839. National Center for Research on Evaluation, Standards, and Student Testing (CRESST).

Maydeu-Olivares, A. (2013). Goodness-of-fit assessment of item response theory models. Measurement: Interdisciplinary Research and Perspectives, 11(3), 71-101.

Maydeu-Olivares, A. (2014). Evaluating the fit of IRT models. In Handbook of item response theory modeling (pp. 111-127). Routledge.

Maydeu-Olivares, A., & Joe, H. (2006). Limited information goodness-of-fit testing in multidimensional contingency tables. Psychometrika, 71(4), 713-732.